# Laravel - Nest Collection into parent key

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to create JSON Data from Laravel Collection. I have a collection that returns pictures records.
I need to nest this collection which has multiple items into a higher key called **photos** and then convert into Json (toJson() function will be enough I believe)

This is my Collection result and I need to append this into a higher key called **photos**

[image]

Can anyone help me please?
Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you had a variable called `$photos`.

```php
   dd(collect(['photos' => $photos]));
```